# How to combine 2 lists into a dictionary, where keys can have multiple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With the following two lists, which match up, so Alice’s age is 20, Bob’s age is 21, and so on.

```
names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Cathy", "Dan", "Ed", "Frank", "Gary", "Helen", "Irene", "Jack", "Kelly", "Larry"]
ages = [20, 21, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 19, 19, 19, 22, 19]
```

Write a program that combines these lists into a dictionary. The key would be the age and the value would be the name, so keys can have multiple values and would
          look like this:

```
{20: ['Alice', 'Frank', 'Gary'], 
 21: ['Bob'], 
 18: ['Cathy', 'Dan'], 
 19: ['Ed', 'Helen', 'Irene', 'Jack', 'Larry'], 
 22: ['Kelly']}
```

I have tried a few things like this:

newDict = dict(zip(ages, names))
print(newDict)

They all output:
{20: 'Gary', 21: 'Bob', 18: 'Dan', 19: 'Larry', 22: 'Kelly'}

Comment: Please post what you have tried & in what way(s) it is deficient.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Right now, it sounds like you're asking us to do your homework for you, which isn't what Stack Overflow is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
age_name = defaultdict(list)

for age, name in zip(ages, names):
    age_name[age].append(name)
```

Defaultdicts can be super useful. They automatically create a default container for a new key.

**Edit**: Without using defaultdicts

```
age_name = dict()
for age, name in zip(ages, names):
    if age not in age_name.keys():
        age_name[age] = list()
    age_name[age].append(name)
```

Comment: I have to do this without importing anything :(